# How to write filtering query with graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-ruby

Currently we are using graphql/graphql-ruby library. I have wrote few queries and mutations as per our requirement.

I have the below use case, where i am not sure how to implement it,

1. I have already an query/endpoint named `allManagers` which return all manager details.
2. Today i have got requirement to implement another query to return all the managers based on the `region` filter.

I have **2 options to handle this scenario**.

1. Create an optional argument for region , and inside the query i need to check if the region is passed then filter based on region.
2. Use something like https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/7-filtering/ .

Which approach is the correct one ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can accomplish this with either approach. #2 looks a bit more complicated, but maybe is more extensible if you end up adding a ton of different types of filters?

are you going to be asked to select multiple regions?  or negative regions (any region except north america?) - those are the types of questions you want to be  thinking about when choosing an approach.

Sounds like a good conversation to have with a coworker :)

I'd probably opt to start with a simple approach and then change it out for a more complex one when the simple solution isn't solving all of my needs any more.